# parse.com .Net sdk works on windows 7?

Tags: parse-platform, windows-7

I'm trying to understand parse.com, but I can't find any documentation or support about this topic. I'm not sure if the app I will make will work on windows 7, because whenever I try to open the solution on VS, it says I need windows 8.1 is this windows 8 exclusive? or is there any way to run the parse.com app on windows 7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://blog.parse.com/announcements/got-net-parse-now-supports-net-4-5/ Parse works on Windows 7:

> Today, we’re excited to introduce support for .NET 4.5 from our Windows SDK, making it easy to target a wide range of platforms including Windows 7 and Windows Server.